# Deleting items from a list when they meet certain criteria

Tags: list-manipulation, pattern-matching

I have a list:

```
lis = {{"a", "xx", "b"}, {"c", "18", "d"}, {"a", "23", "b"}, {"w", "xx", "z"}}
```

I would like to obtain:

```
res = {{"c", 18, "d"}, {"a", "23", "b"}, {"w", "xx", "z"}}
```

where items are dropped from `lis` if their middle sub-element is `"xx"` **and** another element in `lis` contains the same first and last sub-elements and has digit characters in its middle sub-element.  Sorting by `lis[[1]]` puts the two almost identical items next to each other, but I'm not sure how to use `DeleteCases` here.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`Union`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Union.html):

```
Union[lis, SameTest -> (And[#[[2]] == "xx", #[[{1, 3}]] == #2[[{1, 3}]]] &)]
```

> {{"a", "23", "b"}, {"c", "18", "d"}, {"w", "xx", "z"}}

[`DeleteCases`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DeleteCases.html):

```
cond = And[#[[2]] == "xx" , 
  MatchQ[#[[{1, 3}]], Alternatives @@ Complement[lis, {#}][[All, {1, 3}]]]] &;
DeleteCases[lis, _?cond]
```

> {{"c", "18", "d"}, {"a", "23", "b"}, {"w", "xx", "z"}}

A combination of [`GatherBy`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GatherBy.html) and [`DeleteCases`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DeleteCases.html):

```
Join @@ If[Length @ # > 1, DeleteCases[#, {_, "xx", _}], #] & /@ 
 GatherBy[lis, #[[{1, 3}]] &]
```

> {{"a", "23", "b"}, {"c", "18", "d"}, {"w", "xx", "z"}}